# Requesting text from a table row using jquery returns ''

Tags: javascript, html, jquery

I started using jQuery around a week ago and I wanted to make something like a search from an existing table.

When calling `text()` from any row it shows and empty string `''` making it impossible to compare the searched string to the existing ones in the table.

For example, the following code returns 4 instances of `''`. How can I fix this?

```js
$(document).ready(() => {
  $('#test tr').filter(() => {
    console.log($(this).text());
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.6.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<table>
  <tbody id="test">
    <tr>
      <td>example</td>
      <td>1</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>example</td>
      <td>2</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>example</td>
      <td>3</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>example</td>
      <td>4</td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There's two problems in your code. Firstly you're using an arrow function so the `this` keyword will point to the outer context, not the `tr` element within the iteration. To fix this use an anonymous function, or receive the `tr` as the argument to the arrow function. I've done the latter in the example below.

The second issue is that you're using `filter()` as an iterator, which is not correct. `filter()` should be used to reduce a set of elements within a jQuery object. As you want to loop in this case, you should just use `each()` instead.

```js
jQuery($ => {
  $('#test tr').each((i, tr) => {
    console.log($(tr).text().trim());
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.6.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<table>
  <tbody id="test">
    <tr>
      <td>example</td>
      <td>1</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>example</td>
      <td>2</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>example</td>
      <td>3</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>example</td>
      <td>4</td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
```